# mongoDB vs relational databases when data can't fit into memory?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database, nosql

First of all, I apologize for my potentially shallow understanding of NoSQL architecture (and databases in general) so try to bear with me.

I'm thinking of using mongoDB to store resources associated with an UUID. The resources can be things such as large image files (tens of megabytes) so it makes sense to store them as files and store just links in my database along with the associated metadata. There's also the added flexibility of decoupling the actual location of the resource files, so I can use a different third party to store the files if I need to.

Now, one document which describes resources would be about 1kB. At first I except a couple hundred thousands of resource documents which would equal some hundreds of megabytes in database size, easily fitting into server memory. But in the future I might have to scale this into the order of tens of *MILLIONS* of documents. This would be tens of gigabytes which I can't squeeze into server memory anymore.

Only the index could still fit in memory being around a gigabyte or two. But if I understand correctly, I'd have to read from disk every time I did a lookup on an UUID. Is there a substantial speed benefit from mongoDB over a traditional relational database in such a situation?

BONUS QUESTION: is there an existing, established way of doing what I'm trying to achieve? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't suddenly become slow the second the entire database no longer fits into physical memory. MongoDB currently uses a storage engine based on memory mapped files. This means data that is accessed often will usually be in memory (OS managed, but assume a LRU scheme or something similar).

As such it may not slow down at all at that point or only slightly, it really depends on your data access patterns. Similar story with indexes, if you (right) balance your index appropriately and if your use case allows it you can have a huge index with only a fraction of it in physical memory and still have very decent performance with the majority of index hits happening in physical memory.

Because you're talking about UUID's this might all be a bit hard to achieve since there's no guarantee that the same limited group of users are generating the vast majority of throughput. In those cases sharding really is the most appropriate way to maintain quality of service.

Comment: FFR, here's one author sortof showing how MongoDB is fast "until your data no longer fits in memory": http://schmichael.com/files/schmongodb/Scaling%20with%20MongoDB%20(with%20notes).pdf . His graph looks scary, but he doesn't go into much detail about the methodology behind his "benchmark". Sounds like MongoDB just wasn't what he needed.

Comment: It does look scary. Such performance patterns are typical only when the data no longer fits into memory AND the OS having to swap in/out pages of memory a lot due to completely random writes/reads. Such scenarios can usually be easily avoided in real-life scenarios but most benchmarks tend to do things (intentionally) random.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  This would be tens of gigabytes which I can't squeeze into server
> ```
>
> memory anymore.

That's why MongoDB gives you sharding to partition your data across multiple mongod instances (or replica sets).

Comment: I was under the impression that mongoDB sharding would be similar to the partitioning features in relational databases. Now I did some research it seems that I'd either have to pay a hefty license fee for Oracle or MSSQL Enterprise or make do with MySQL's immature partitioning support. Postgresql seems a little better (Skype is using it with a system called PL/Proxy), but still slower than mongo. Now I'll just have to convince my boss to buy some more servers!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to considering sharding, or maybe even before, you should also try to use covered indexes as much as possible, especially if it fits your Use cases.

This way you do not HAVE to load entire documents into memory. Your indexes can help out.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-CoveredIndexes

Comment: My most prominent use case would be displaying all the resources associated with a given ID, so I'd have to retrieve the whole document anyway. Or do you mean that I could store my actual files inside the JSON documents as embedded blobs, just not retrieving them until needed?

Comment: Do most of your heavy queries mandate that you will have to return the entire document to the user? If so, then covered indexes will nt be of big help. But if you can reduce a few o your use cases to return only a subsection of the entire document, and leverage covered indexes, it should help out in performance and scalability.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to display your entire document all the time based on the id, then the general rule of thumb is to attempt to keep e working set in memory.

http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/12/13/mongodb-monitoring-keep-in-it-ram/

This is one of the resources that talks about that. There is a video on mongodb's site too that speaks about this.

By attempting to size the ram so that the working set is in memory, and also looking at sharding, you will not have to do this right away, you can always add sharding later. This will improve scalability of your app over time.

Again, these are not absolute statements, these are general guidelines, that you should think through your usage patterns and make sure that they ar relevant to what you are doing.

Personally, I have not had the need to fit everything in ram.